# How to solve query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some database I need to query.
It is necessary to write a query that finds out how many times the teams played among themselves. It is important if Team A plays against Team B and then Team B plays against Team A, it counts as the same event. That is, the result should be: A against B - 2 games.

```sql
SELECT
     least(home_team, away_team) AS A
    ,greatest(home_team, away_team) AS B
    ,COUNT(*) AS games_count
FROM event_entity
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1                        
ORDER BY A, B
```

I have this query.

But need this solve.
3 first rows in solving

```
Novara-Udinese 1 
Brescia-Genoa 1 
Fc Pacos de Ferreira - Trofense 1
```

This is my schema:

[image]

Comment: Please include sample data and expected outcome as text ,which we can use, rather than links which we can't.

Comment: I edited your post to show your schema - please replace the screenshot of your data with text to allow people here to create an answer without being forced to re-type your data.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1`??? Doesn't filter anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the query that you need to build on the logic of getting the number of count of games. In order to display the event you can do as follows.

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(home_team,'-',away_team)) as game
     ,COUNT(*) AS games_count
 FROM event_entity
GROUP BY least(home_team, away_team), greatest(home_team, away_team)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: It's good solve, but in solves i have 3 first rows:
Novara-Udinese 1
Brescia-Genoa 1
Fc Pacos de Ferreira - Trofense 1

Comment: can you explain a bit

Comment: I have an example of a conclusion that has to come out and there are three first columns that I have described above. And in my decision and yours, there is no case of them playing once.

Comment: use the filter HAVING COUNT(*)>1

Comment: I only get values from 2.

Comment: what is your expected output?. Provide the output in the question,

Comment: Thanks, i'm solve this problem!